Acceso bloqueado: Error de Autorizacion. Autenticacion con Google en MAUI
estoy intentando agregar autenticacion a mi aplicacion con MAUI. Segui un post en donde lo implementaban y todo funciona correctamente hablando del codigo o eso pienso yo ya que al querer logearme con Google me abre la ventana de Iniciar sesion con google pero me dice Acceso bloqueado: Error de autorizacion
Asi esta mi consola de Google cloud
Y el codigo que uso


     public async Task LoginWithGoogle()
 {

     var authUri = configuration.GetSection("Google").GetValue<string>("authUri");
     var clientId = configuration.GetSection("Google").GetValue<string>("clientId");
     var scope = configuration.GetSection("Google").GetValue<string>("scope");
     var redirectUri = "com.tutrono://oauth";

     var authUrl = $"{authUri}?response_type=code" +
                   $"&redirect_uri=com.tutrono://oauth" +
                   $"&client_id={clientId}" +
                   $"&scope={scope}" +
                   $"&include_granted_scopes=true" +
                   $"&state=state_parameter_passthrough_value";
         
     var callbackUrl = "com.tutrono://oauth";

     try
     {
         var response = await WebAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync(new WebAuthenticatorOptions()
         {
             Url = new Uri(authUrl),
             CallbackUrl = new Uri(callbackUrl)
         });

         var codeToken = response.Properties["code"];

         var parameters = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
         {
         new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "authorization_code"),
         new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", configuration.GetSection("Google").GetValue<string>("clientId")),
         new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect_uri", callbackUrl),
         new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code", codeToken)
     });

         HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
         var accessTokenResponse = await client.PostAsync(configuration.GetSection("Google").GetValue<string>("tokenUri"), parameters);

         if (accessTokenResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
         {
             var data = await accessTokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

         }
     }
     catch (TaskCanceledException e)
     {
             
     }

 }





namespace TuTronoMovil.Platforms.Android
{

    [Activity(NoHistory =true, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop, Exported =true)]
      [IntentFilter(new[] { global::Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
     Categories = new[] { global::Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault, global::Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
      DataScheme = "com.tutrono")]
    public class WebAuthenticatorActivity : WebAuthenticatorCallbackActivity
    {

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }
    }
}



No tengo idea de que pueda ser, no encontre informacion acerca de esto, no sé si haya alguna libreria para implementarlo directamente o si es necesario usar webauthtentication

Por el error que obtienes, te sugiero primeramente revisar si tienes configurados todos los datos de la ventana de consentimiento OAuth

Es importante también que la huella del certificado SHA-1 que configuras sea del keystore con la que firmas la app, esto para poder usar la API, ya que es muy común que se registra una "Client ID for Android" con un SHA-1 obtenido del Keystore de desarrollo cuando la app se encuentra en Google Play o viceversa, cuando se obtiene el SHA-1 del Keystore con la que firmas tu app para Google Play pero estás subiendo tu app desde Android Studio, que en este caso se firma con el Keystore de desarrollo.
Revisa este caso:
Google Maps Android se visualiza en gris (o blanco) en Release

Si, creo que los tengo configurados ya que solo me aparece para publicar la app, se me paso decir que esto me esta pasando en desarrollo. Entonces creo que si.
Eso que me comentas de el certificado SHA-1 fue un rollo para mi porque no sabia como hacerlo hasta que vi esta pagina y lo genere de esa manera pero no tengo idea si fue la manera correcta https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/keystore-signature?tabs=windows
Google Cloud en esa parte da un comando para generarla pero no supe donde meterlo hasta que vi el link de arriba
